# fbconnect API response in iPhone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, fbconnect

I am calling the FaceBook API like this:

```
-(IBAction)testBtnAct:(id)sender{
    [facebookObj requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
}
-(IBAction)test1BtnAct:(id)sender{
    [facebookObj requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
}
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    NSLog(@"request didLoad..%@",result);
};
```

The issue is that if I am clicking the both button(testBtnAct and test1BtnAct) and then output comes into `- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result` in `result` variable.

Then how do we know which result comes `result` valuable (i.e for `me` OR `me/friends`)?

Comment: in NSLog. u will get about the result ah? it will vary know

Comment: its just log the array... there is no specific different in result that I will distinct these two programmatic..not only these two as there are other API options too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the request url string of your request parameter in the didload method.

Comment: which method call when controls comes to application back after login success/fail from UIWebView